# combine two scopes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two scopes and need to combine them. Does anyone know the best way to do this? below are the two scopes. the second one comes from a service

The first scope, retrieves info from database using PHP SLIM RESTful API

```
Data.get('posts').then(function(data){
        $scope.posts = data.data;
    });
```

The second scope retrieves info from database via a service

```
dataShare.getconfigs().then(function(data){
        $scope.configs = data;
    });
```

UPDATE:
When I open the modal to edit I only get the $scope.posts. I am not currently passing through the $scope.configs

```
$scope.open = function (p,size) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'views/postsEdit.html',
          controller: 'postsEditCtrl',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            item: function () {
              return p;
            }
          }
        }); ...
```

Comment: What is the structure of the initial scopes and what is the expected result?

Comment: I don't understand. I need them to be in one scope

Comment: They are now on the same scope..??? Maybe you're confusing terms? Do you mean different controllers?

Comment: My mistake you are correct. I updated the post to show my problem

Comment: Can you provide a fiddler or plunkr to show the controllers?

Comment: You can share the scope with the modal: `scope: $scope`, then you have access to the same scope object in your modal as in your other view

Comment: can you show me how the code would look?

Comment: I have successfully added the scope to the modal, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$modal.open` will create new *isolated* scope which will be used inside of modal controller and template. This new scope is going to be a direct child of the `$rootScope`, and thus it will not inherit from your `$scope`. However, what you want is to inherit from the `$scope` object from which you open a modal. For this configure modal like this:

```
$scope.open = function(p, size) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/postsEdit.html',
    controller: 'postsEditCtrl',
    size: size,
    scope: $scope, // <-- use $scope as a parent to for modal scope
    resolve: {
      item: function() {
        return p;
      }
    }
  });
};
```